# git push on a new branch: automate

Tags: git

Any time I open a branch (and I need one per ticket) and I try to do just `git push` I get

```
fatal: The current branch testchx has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

  git push --set-upstream origin testchx
```

Is there a way to tell git to automatically do `git push --set-upstream origin testchx` instead of dying with a fatal?

Git version: 1.8.1.4

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to create a `testchx` branch on your central repository? Or do you want to merge `testchx` into `origin/master`?

Comment: `git config push.default current` is *exactly* what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to follow the instruction in the error message:

```
git push --set-upstream origin testchx
```

Another is to set `push.default` behaviour:

```
git config push.default current
```

For more detail:

```
git help config
```